# How to validate overall execution of multiple JUnit 4 tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

### Desired: A "Test of the Tests"

Imagine there is some additional "sanity check" that could be performed after a test class completes all its tests that would indicate whether test execution as a whole executed successfully. This final sanity check could possibly use some aggregated information about the tests. Just as a crude example: The number of calls to a shared method is counted, and if the count is not above some minimum expected threshold after all tests complete, then it is clear that something is wrong even if all the individual tests pass.

What I have described is probably in some "grey area" of best practices because while it **does violate** the doctrine of atomic unit tests, the final sanity check is not actually testing the class being tested; rather, it is checking that test execution as a whole was a success: A "test of the tests," so-to-speak. It is additional logic regarding the tests themselves.

### This Solution Seems Bad

One way to accomplish this "test of tests" is to place the sanity check in a static `@AfterClass` method. If the check fails, one can call `Assert.fail()`, which actually works (surprisingly, since I presumed it could only be invoked from within methods annotated with `@Test`, which by nature must be instance methods, not static):

```
public class MyTest {

   [...]

    @AfterClass
    public static void testSufficientCount() {
        if (MyTest.counterVariable < MIN_COUNT) {
            Assert.fail("This fail call actually works. Wow.");
        }
    }

}
```

There are many reasons why this solution is a kludge:

- Assume there are `N` tests in total (where a "test" is an instance method annotated with `@Test`). When `Assert.fail()` is **not** called in `@AfterClass`, `N` tests in total are reported by the IDE, as expected. However, when `Assert.fail()` is called in `@AfterClass`, `N + 1` tests in total are reported by the IDE (the extra one being the static `@AfterClass` method). The additional static method was **not** annotated with `@Test`, so it should not be counted as a test. Further, the total number of tests should not be a function of whether some tests pass or fail.
- The `@AfterClass` method is static by definition. Therefore, only static members are accessible. This presents a problem for my specific situation; I will leave this statement without elaboration because the explanation is out of the scope of the question, but basically it would be most desirable if only instance members were used.
- *[Other reasons too...]*

### Is There a Better Way?

Is there a way to implement this "test of tests" that is considered good and common practice? Does JUnit 4 support adding some kind of logic to ensure a group of unit tests within a class executed properly (failing in some way if they did not)? Is there a name for this thing I have called a "test of tests"?

Comment: What's the point? You already get a report of whether everything succeeded or failed. If you want more detailed reporting, that's what the JUnit report, which is understood by every major tool, is for.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- The point is described in the first paragraph of the question along with a crude example to illustrate the point; I am not sure how else to describe it. Here is another way to phrase it: There is some custom condition(s) specific to the set of tests that can be checked; it is desired to check this condition after the tests run to serve as a verification that the tests as a whole succeeded.

Comment: @NathanHughes That is an interesting suggestion. I searched around and found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_code_coverage_tools. Unfortunately this may be a cannon to kill a mosquito in this case.

Comment: Could you give examples of problems that you would like to catch with your test-of-the-tests?

Answer (score 1):

#### About variable number of tests

I don't think there is a valid solution ...

#### About static fields

I tried to follow your example and, if I understood well, with a combination of [Verifier](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/Verifier.html), [TestRule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) and [ClassRule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html) it is possible to use only the instance fields of the test class

Here my code from which to take a cue:

```
public class ATest {

    public int countVariable = 0;

    private static class MyVerifier extends Verifier {

        public int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void verify() throws Throwable {
            assertTrue(count < 1); // cause new failed test
        //  assertTrue(count >= 1);  // it's all ok
        }

    }

    @ClassRule
    public static MyVerifier v = new MyVerifier();

    private class MyRule implements TestRule {

        ATest a;
        MyVerifier v;

        public MyRule(ATest a, MyVerifier v) {
            this.a = a;
            this.v = v;
        }

        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            try {

                base.evaluate();
                this.v.count = a.countVariable;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ATest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return base;
        }

    }

    @Rule
    public MyRule rule = new MyRule(this, v);

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        countVariable++; // modifies instance counter
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testSomeMethod2() {
        countVariable++; // modifies instance counter
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

#### Having said that

"test of tests" isn't consider a common and good practice because, as you know, it violates at least two of five principles of the FIRST rule(see [Cleean code from Uncle Bob Martin](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/books)): tests must be

- F: Fast
- I: Indipendent
- R: Repeteable
- S: Self-validating
- T: Timely (linked to TDD practice)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Renato. I will try your suggestion and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've had time to study your solution a bit (I had to learn more of the JUnit 4 API) and I have a question: Is this much different than having `MyRule` directly update a static counter variable? The reason I ask is because it seems its private `MyVerifier` is simply a reference to the static `MyVerifier`, which keeps the count. In the line `this.v.count = a.countVariable` isn't `this.v` is simply referring to the static `ATest.v`? So, for example, if another class `ATest2` inherited from `ATest`, the two would be sharing the same count variable.